# Synchronise the data from one table to another table using Functions in Postgresql in Regular Intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating two tables in which the data in **table1** should be updated to **table2** for every 5 minutes interval time.

I have created two tables using

```
CREATE TABLE table1(id int not null,name varchar(50);

CREATE TABLE table2(id int not null,name varchar(50);
```

now I want the data that is present in the table1 should be synchronized with table2 in every 5 minutes interval

I don't know how can it be done...

Answer (score 0):

A `pg_cron` job scheduler might be started to repeat your task for every five minutes as

```
select cron.schedule('*/5 * * * *', $$insert into table2 select * from table1 
 where id not in ( select id from table2 )$$);
```

provided your operating system is `linux`. `*/5 * * * *` part should be replaced with `0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *` for `solaris` operating system.

```
select cron.unschedule(jobid) FROM cron.job;
```

may be used to unschedule the task.